# Does Metal Slug 2 Mobile support cross platform Bluetooth play?

Tags: ios, android, metal-slug-2

My friend and I have Metal Slug 2 for iOS and Android. The game supports Bluetooth play, but we cannot link the iPhone 5 and Nexus 7. Why is this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, metal slug 2 can only work for android or any other compatible devices with bluetooth. playing an ios with other os over bluetooth doesnt work because apple designed it only for apple products.